# Insert Item in UICollectionView dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm working on a requirement where I need to add the items in a `UICollectionView` dynamically.

Here is my code of `ViewController`

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    enum Direction {
        case Horizonatal
        case Verticle
    }

    var enumDirection: Direction = .Verticle
    var direction = "Verticle"
    var SectionsAndRows = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        SectionsAndRows.append(4)
        SectionsAndRows.append(3)
        SectionsAndRows.append(2)
        SectionsAndRows.append(1)
        //SectionsAndRows.append(5)
    }

    @IBOutlet var gridCollectionView: UICollectionView! {
        didSet {
            gridCollectionView.bounces = false
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet var gridLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout! {
        didSet {
            //gridLayout.stickyRowsCount = 0
            gridLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            //gridLayout.stickyColumnsCount = 0
            gridLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
            gridLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
        }
    }
 }

// MARK: - Collection view data source and delegate methods

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return SectionsAndRows.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(SectionsAndRows[section])
        return SectionsAndRows[section]
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CollectionViewCell.reuseID, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell else {
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
        print("Current Section ==\(indexPath.section) CurrentRow ===\(indexPath.row) and its rows count ==\(SectionsAndRows[indexPath.section])")

        cell.titleLabel.text = ""
        cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleAdd(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.btn.tag = (indexPath.section * 1000) + indexPath.row
        if enumDirection == .Verticle {
            if indexPath.section == SectionsAndRows.count - 1 {
                cell.btn.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
            } else {
                cell.btn.setTitle("\(indexPath)", for: .normal)
            }

        }
        return cell
    }

    @objc func handleAdd(sender: UIButton) {
        // Perform some opration
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

CollectionViewCell.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseID = "CollectionViewCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
}
```

If you run the code, it will show a Collection of 1 row and 1 column in each row. If you uncomment the last line of `viewDidLoad()` (`SectionsAndRows.append(5)`) function, then it works fine.

My observation is that the last section of the `CollectionView` will have the highest number of a column. Is that correct or is this a bug of a CollectionView?

Comment: Can you state your question exactly? What is that you need help with? Your observation happens: when ```SectionsAndRows.append(5)``` is commented or when uncommented?

Comment: @Starsky, I want to show 4 items in first section, 3 items in second section and so on. But all the section shows only 1 item. Now uncomment the last line. It will show all the items correctly. So, my question is, is this a bug or is there any work around for that?

Comment: I'm assuming you're setting the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` in Storyboard, since I don't see it in your code anywhere.  In that case it seems you are never reloading the data with `reloadData` after you adjust your `SectionsAndRows`, right?  Or did you just not post that part?

Comment: That I've set from the storyboard. Did you get a chance to run the code @creeperspeak

Comment: Do you have an image of your desired result? Do you want your individual sections to scroll horizontal, while the other sections stay still? Maybe you need a more complex approach to what you want to achieve.